# How to Export data from WebBrowser to Excel using C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I have taken the data from a web browser. Now I want to export the data from the web browser to excel.

I get data from web browser such formats:

```
1
    20 143
    10 180
    1 653
    8 310
    1 280
    1 280
    1 280

    1 280
    :
    :
    :

    2
    19 339
    9 800
    1 767
    7 773
    1 280
    1 280
    1 280

    1 280
    H2:DA_MI
    H2:DA_MI
    H2:DA_MI
```

Comment: I tried to cover from RichText via excel but not cover :(

Comment: What do you mean by RichText?

Comment: I used RichText show data I get, now i want cover data from the RichText via excel

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean by RichText, but I suggest you take a look at EPPlus. But by saying `web browser`, you mean your application page right?